# Query to get termID, term name and number of posts that has that term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I can figure out how to construct a db query that fetches term id and term name. But how do I associate a count of nid's that has this term? I'm looking to do this programatically through the DB api.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm running low on time.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a separate query to select nodes with term id = x, then execute the rowCount method on the resultset like:

```
$results = $query->execute();
$num = $results->rowCount();
```

([Source](http://drupal.org/node/1226410#comment-4797378))

But more direct approach is using addExpression, join and groupBy:

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd');
$query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'ttd.tid = ti.tid');
$query->fields('ttd', array('tid', 'name'));
$query->groupBy('ti.tid');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(ti.nid)', 'nid_count');

$results = $query->execute();
```

You can also use db_query straight away:

```
$results = db_query('SELECT ttd.`tid`, ttd.`name`, COUNT(ti.`nid`) AS `nid_count` FROM `taxonomy_term_data` ttd JOIN `taxonomy_index` ti ON ttd.`tid` = ti.`tid` GROUP BY ti.`tid`');
```